# In Java how many constructor can we create in one class?

Tags: java

In Java, how many constructors can we create within a single class.

Comment: You can create as many as you need

Comment: Duplicates with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490661/how-many-constructors-should-a-class-have

Comment: How many **can** you? I imagine there is an upper bound, but I have never encountered it in practice. I would speculate it is on the order of tens of thousands. But I haven't tested that. It probably depends on the compiler and its' version too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many constructors should a class have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490661/how-many-constructors-should-a-class-have)

Comment: The number of methods in a class is limited to 65535. So I guess the number of constructors is limited to 65535 too.

Comment: Gah, these answer are **wrong** and now the, perhaps pointless without context but entirely reasonable, question is closed.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline which bit are you saying is wrong? What's the TL;DR of your answer?

Comment: @AndyTurner The 65535 bit. I claim it is **65527**, probably. On another note,  this very similar question has **28 upvotes**: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4342072/4725

Comment: No hang on. It's **65530**, but that is with "cheating". Reopen now!

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Voting to reopen.

Comment: Voting to reopen.

Comment: Voted and reopened.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline it depends on the compiler options. E.g. including debug information will reduce the number. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742619/2711488) explains the details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the JVM classfile format limits the number of methods (including all constructors) for a class to less than 65536.  And according to Tom Hawtin, the effective limit is 65527.  Each method signature occupies a slot in the constant pool.  Since some of the 65535 pool entries are (unavoidably) consumed by other things, it is not possible for a well-formed class file to use all of the possible method / constructor ids.

Reference - [JVMS 4.1 The ClassFile Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)

However, if you are writing sensible Java code the normal way, you won't encounter that limit.

How many *should* you have?  It depends on the classes use-cases.  It is often nice to have multiple "convenience" constructor overloads, and implement them using `this(...)` to chain to a "master" constructor.  (However, you can go over the top.  There are N! possible combinations (overloads) of N distinct parameters.)

If you find that you are writing an excessive (subjective!) number of constructors, you should maybe look at alternatives such as the [Builder Pattern](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html).

Answer (score 13):

Like with [the maximum number of lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866991/2711488) or [the maximum of nested method invocations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112260/2711488), we have to make a distinction between the formal Java language specification and technical limits, either due to the formally specified class file format or due to compiler limitations or bugs.

As often, the language specification does not define any limits on the number of constructors. So there’s only the practical limitation that the class declaration must be representable in the byte code format.

Constructors get compiled to special methods (named `<init>`), so in the class file, they share a table with ordinary methods, which is limited to 65535 entries. We can max this out by not declaring any ordinary methods. Further, since every constructor must have a distinct signature, each constructor needs its own type signature string in the constant pool, which is limited to 65534 entries on its own.

The constant pool also serves other purposes, like holding the declaration of this class, super class and the name of the `Code` attribute, which is needed when having constructors, as well as the linkage information of the super class’ constructor, we have to invoke, so this is the limiting factor on the class file side.

So the minimum constant pool entries needed, are

1. super class name (modified UTF8 entry)
2. super class (type Class, referring to 1.)
3. this class name (modified UTF8 entry)
4. this class (type Class, referring to 3.)
5. the constructor’s “method” name `<init>` (modified UTF8 entry)
6. a name&type entry referring to 5. and a super constructor signature (may be shared with one of our constructor’s signature)
7. a method entry referring to 2. and 6. (for the super constructor invocation)
8. the attribute name `Code` (modified UTF8 entry)

Given these required entries and the limit of 65534 entries (the size plus one is stored as unsigned two byte quantity), we get a class file limit of 65526 constructors and indeed, I could generate a valid class file using the ASM library with that number of constructors and not more.

Actually, you could get more if you name your class `java.lang.Object`, as in that special case, there is no super class to declare and no super constructor to invoke. Decide yourself, which actual limit you want to call the maximum number…

As said, there is a 3rd limitation, the compiler implementation. When using a Java compiler, you have to make sure that it doesn’t generate debug information (in case of `javac`, use `-g:none`) and no other optional attributes which could occupy constant pool entries. But with `javac` of JDK11, the performance will drop significantly when you start defining lots of constructors. I got the following compilation times:

```
 1000 constructors:   1 second
 2000 constructors:   2 seconds
 5000 constructors:  10 seconds
10000 constructors:   1 minute
15000 constructors:   2 minutes
20000 constructors:   4 minutes
30000 constructors:  10 minutes
40000 constructors:  20 minutes
50000 constructors:  between 25 minutes and ½ hour
65526 constructors:  between 45 minutes and 1 hour
```

So `javac` eventually managed to max out the class file limit, but we may consider a practical limit even before that.

The Eclipse compiler seems to deal better with such source files, but still, maxing out the number of constructors made the IDE almost unusable. With debug symbols turned off and a bit of patience, I managed to compile a class with 65526 constructors with Eclipse. Declaring 65528 constructors pro­duced an error message regarding too many constant pool entries and declaring 65527 constructors revealed a bug in Eclipse, producing a corrupt class file declaring zero constant pool entries (as said earlier, the number is stored as *count plus one*, so compiler vendors have to keep in mind that the limit is not 65535 but 65534).

Comment: If anyone wonders who would construct classes like that.. [here is the UI implementation of the Telegram App](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/e9e40cb13ea942b148b259c083fb3364a0cd90ea/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/ChatActivity.java)

Answer (score 2):

Java Support Constructor Overloading(When java class contain multiple constructors, it is called as constructor is overloaded).A class can have multiple constructors, as long as their signature(parameter) are not the same.So you can define many constructors as you need.There is no limit.
Here is a Example:-

```
class Demo {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private Double salary;

    public Demo() {
    }

    public Demo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Demo(Double salary) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public Demo(String name,String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Here is an example" your example wouldn't compile, because you have two constructors with the same signature.

Answer (score 2):

You can have 65535 constructors in a class(According to Oracle docs). But IMPORTANTLY keep this in your mind. We achieve this only by CONSTRUCTOR OVERLOADING ( https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/constructor-overloading/ ). You can create many constructors but with different signatures.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

For a class with reasonable functionality you will first run into other problems, both technical and non-technical. Technical limits imposed by the constant pool of the class file format for a useless class are:

- 65526 for a class with a name of your choosing.
- 65527 for a class named `Code` (one per class loader).
- 65530 for a class named `java.lang.Object` (one per VM).

**The details**

The question was closed before I had posted my answer. So here's bits additional to that which @Holger has already covered.

The relevant section of the JVM spec is [4.1. The ClassFile Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1) in the Java SE 11 edition.

```
u2             constant_pool_count;
cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
```

Note the `-1`. The entries are numbered from 1. 0 is used to indicate:

- a class with no superclass (interesting!)
- a formal parameter with no name
- a module with no version information
- a module dependence with no version information

If the class is called `Code` then this string constant will be deduped with the required `Code` attribute name (see @Holger's answer). You will need a very old version of `javac` if you want to access it from outside of the default package.

It may be possible to remove a couple of the entries, if writing in byte code is not cheating, by throwing `null` (not a constant in bytecode) instead of calling `super()` or similar. I can't remember the exact details of bytecode verification for constructors - they certain cannot terminate normally without calling a `this()` or a `super()`.

`javac` running increasingly slowly (O(n^2)ish?) is a good example of graceful degradation. :)

**Playtime**

You can see this for yourself quite easily by compiling small classes with varying numbers of constructors.

```
public class Min1 {
   public Min1() {
   }
   /* Followed by (int a), (byte a), (int a, byte b), etc. */
}
```

Compile without debug info (do people still accidentally distribute class files with debug info?).

```
javac -g:none Min1.java
```

List contents with good old `javap`.

```
javap -verbose Min1
```

Should give you something like

```
Classfile /Users/tackline/code/scratch/minimal_class/Min1.class
  Last modified Dec 5, 2018; size 119 bytes
  MD5 checksum c1a6b7c31c286165e01cc4ff240e7718
public class Min1
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #3.#7          // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #8             // Min1
   #3 = Class              #9             // java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               <init>
   #5 = Utf8               ()V
   #6 = Utf8               Code
   #7 = NameAndType        #4:#5          // "<init>":()V
   #8 = Utf8               Min1
   #9 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public Min1();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many constructors in a class as you wish.. JAVA doesn't impose any restrictions on the number of constructors a class can have.. Just that constructors can be either parameterized or default..

**default constructor:** Default constructor does not have a parameters and is used to initialize every object with same data.

**parametrized constructor:** Parameterized constructor is having one or more parameters and  is used to initialized each object with different data.

Answer (score -1):

You can create 65535 constructors in one class

More information: [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11)

Comment: Previous answers have established that isn't quite accurate, and the linked JVM spec doesn't explicitly say for constructors.

Answer (score -2):

There's no limit on the number of constructors a class can have.

Comment: 65535 actually: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11